# How to know the impacts of reverting a pushed Git commit when successive commits depends on it?

Tags: git

Consider the following scenario, as part of commit, C1, a file is created and pushed to the remote repo.
This commit is pulled by different members and updates are done on the file created in C1. The commits are pushed to the remote repo.
Now `git revert C1`, will delete the file. It will not warn us about the successive changes that have been performed on this file.
Is there a better way to undo a commit, fully understanding the impact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now git revert C1, will delete the file

No, it won't. You'll get a merge conflict, and that is your chance to consider the implications of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks @matt. I overlooked that git reported about the conflict on git revert.

Comment: I should add, however, that in general thinking is up to you. Any time you `git revert` a commit that is not the HEAD, something "interesting" is about to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the file has been modified, reverting C1 won't just delete it. You will get a tree conflict and then you will have to see what to do about it.